# Get stream and read contents

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a Procedure that will return a `ClientResult<Stream>` and  I want to output the contents of the file here is what i have so far,

```
        ClientResult<Stream> stream = ProcedureToReturnStream(args)

        string strHtml = string.Empty;

        using (MemoryStream memStr = new MemoryStream())
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 64];
            int nread = 0;

            while ((nread = stream.Value.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                memStr.Write(buffer, 0, nread);
            }

            memStr.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(memStr))
            {
                memStr.Position = 0;
                strHtml = sr.ReadToEnd();
            }

        }
        Console.WriteLine(strHtml);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

My issue is this error: `System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException`